# convert array to treeview in php

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

How to convert array to treeview in php

Below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [efi] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [grub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fonts] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [i386-pc] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [locale] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [x86_64-efi] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want output as treeview

- efi
- grub

and under grub I want

- fonts
- i386-pc
- locale
- x86_64-efi

I have used below code for same

```
function generateTreeMenu($dir_array, $parent = 0, $limit=0){
            if($limit > 1000) return '';
            $tree = '';
            $tree = '<ul>';
            for($i=0, $ni=count($dir_array); $i < $ni; $i++){
                if($dir_array[$i]['parent_id'] == $parent){
                    $tree .= '<li><a>';
                    $tree .= $dir_array[$i]['title'].'</a>';
                    $tree .= generatePageTree($dir_array, $dir_array[$i]['id'], $limit++);
                    $tree .= '</li>';
                }
            }
            $tree .= '</ul>';
            return $tree;
}

generateTreeMenu($dir_array);
```

it show warning
Undefined property: stdClass::$parent_id in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php tree ul li hierarchy menu from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003141/php-tree-ul-li-hierarchy-menu-from-array)

Comment: @AliAlwash This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have multidimensional array.

Comment: Please post generatePageTree(), we cannot replicate your code and try it without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, based on your post:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$dir_array = array( array( "efi"  => array() ),
                    array( "grub" => array(
                                           array("fonts"      => array()),
                                           array("i386-pc"    => array()),
                                           array("locale"     => array()),
                                           array("x86_64-efi" => array())
                                          )
                         )
                  );
print_r($dir_array);
echo "</pre>\n";

function mygenerateTreeMenu($dir_array,$limit = 0)
{
    $key = '';
    if ($limit > 1000) return '';
    foreach ($dir_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!is_int($key))
        {
            $tree .= "<li>";
            $tree .= "<a>$key</a><ul>";
            $tree .= mygenerateTreeMenu($value,$limit++);
            $tree .= "</ul></li>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $tree .= mygenerateTreeMenu($value,$limit++);
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

echo "<ul>\n";
$tree = mygenerateTreeMenu($dir_array);
echo $tree;
echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

I removed the $parent as I did not need it.  Then because of the way your array is built, integer indexes are ignored.  If you can modify your array, you could streamline it and remove integer indexes completely and treat is as a hash table.  It would make the recursive code simpler.