# Prestashop display product categories and subcategories

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

On the product page I want to display all categories and subcategories to which the product is assigned. Something like this:
-Category 1
--Sub1
--Sub2
-Category 2
--Sub3
--Sub4

My current code is:

```
{foreach from=$product_categories item=product_category}
                    {if $product_category.id_category != 2}
                        <li >
                            <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($product_category.id_category, $product_category.link_rewrite)}"
                            title="{$product_category.name}">{$product_category.name}</a>
                        </li>   
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
```

But its print all categories in every line without category tree.

Comment: try som render function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003141/php-tree-ul-li-hierarchy-menu-from-array but make sure you have "level" variable to create proper ul/li hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a nested function to generate a tree and then you can display it at the page, like what Prestashop did in the Blockcategories module.

Why don't you use this module (Blockcategories) as a pattern?

Comment: How to use blockcategories to show assigned categories to product on product page? Right after description

Comment: I mean that is the easiest way is to copy this module and develope it.